# Regular Expression match this string

Tags: regex

i have a this strings

```
01 - Il visitatore - Lia and me II
```

i write this regex

> (\d*).*-?.*-\s

but match only number. as a result I would

```
Group1: 01 
Group2: Il visitatore misterioso
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to a programming code, you could easily split the string with "space"-"hyphen"-"space", and get the necessary items.

With a regex, you may use

```
^(\d+)\s*-\s*([^-]+)\s
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/o9hPfk/1)

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(\d+)` - Group 1 capturing 1 or more digits
- `\s*-\s*` - a hyphen enclosed with 0+ whitespaces
- `([^-]+)`  - Group 2 capturing 1+ chars other than `-`, as many as possible (the `+` quantifier is *greedy*)
- `\s` - a whitespace

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps!

```js
var string = '01 - Il visitatore misterioso - Mia and me II';
var regex = /^(\d{2})\s\-\s([\w\s]+)\-[\w\s]+$/;
var matches = regex.exec(string);

console.log('Group 1:', matches[1])
console.log('Group 2:', matches[2])
```